# java.lang.NullPointerException: uri at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull

Tags: java, android, uri

I'm using multipart upload for image uploading in query submit form, In my case image uploading is optional so when I not use image it throws null pointer so I need it should be optional

```
 public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = AskQueryActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null); // this line throws error
        assert cursor != null;
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        cursor.close();

        cursor = AskQueryActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        assert cursor != null;
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();

        return path;
    }
```

error logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.admin.lorem.ipsum, PID: 3818
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
                      at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:60)
                      at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:474)
                      at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
```

Comment: it's pretty obvious that your uri is null, debug your app and see why.

Comment: @S.Aslpour yes Its null as I said it null when I'm not using image upload

Comment: so add an if and check when it's null, set your cursor null :|

Comment: you are selecting a table from your database ... so you can't do it with a null uri

Comment: @S.Aslpour ok I'll set cursor null and let you know

Comment: @S.Aslpour cursor = null not worked. :|

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151180/discussion-between-s-aslpour-and-omi).

Comment: How this is solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do  null-check on uri and return null from getPath if uris is null. Avoid your getPath method to do anything if uri is null.

The caller of getPath must react to that null and do whatever you need to do if result is null.

Or better, avoid caller to execute getPath if uri is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intentt = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intentt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION & Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Just add this in intent or in ActivityResult.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED){
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {  
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @albert_nil state [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45529332/6834114) that do check `URI` should not be null to perform `Cursor query` and if `URI` still return `null` then handle this by `Toast or log` like below

```
 public String getPath(Uri uri) {
  if(uri != null){
    Cursor cursor = AskQueryActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null); // this line throws error
    assert cursor != null;
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
    document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = AskQueryActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    assert cursor != null;
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();

    return path;
  } else{
     //do log/toast to user
     return "";
  }
}
```